# Tkinter: Tk() não encontrado

Tags: python, tkinter

Ao tentar chamar a função Tk(), o mesmo não é reconhecido aparecendo a seguinte mensagem:
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined

Estou tentando iniciar o seguinte código:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

Label(root, text="teste").pack()

root.mainloop
```

Estou com o python 3.8.0 instalado, utilizando com Pycharm (ja fiz instalação do tkinter no gerenciador de pacotes), ja instalei o tcl (vi que poderia ajudar). Ja modifiquei a escrita de importação do tkinter variando entre minúscula e maiúscula a primeira letra. Porém sem resultados por enquanto. Alguma dica de como posso resolver esta situação?
Desde já agradeço a atenção de quem se propor a contribuir :)

Comment: Eu sei que é uma pergunta bem boba essa que eu vou fazer, mas surpreendentemente isto ocorre muitas vezes. Você já verificou se não existe um `tkinter.py` no mesmo diretório do seu programa não ? Caso exista, você estará importando este módulo que certamente não contém o `Tk()`.

Comment: Eu fiz uma edição dessa vez (que está esperando aprovação), mas quando for colocar código, sempre selecione a parte do código e aperte ctrl + k

Comment: esta usando linux? quando eu faço uma nova instalação de distro, tambem instalo o idle, é garantido que o tkinter vir junto, pois o idle é feito em tk

Comment: Resolvido! O problema era que eu tinha colocado o nome do arquivo de tkinter.py sendo que esse nome não pode ser usado no arquivo por ser uma palavra reservada pela ferramenta (foi o que entendi rsrs).
Agradeço aos amigos que se disponibilizaram a me esclarecer o funcionamento da ferramenta. Sou iniciante e foi de grande ajuda a colaboração de vocês.
Vlw! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se você não tem nomeado o seu arquivo para algo como `tkinter.py`. É um erro comum, mas você não pode nomear um arquivo cujo o nome seja o mesmo de um módulo que esteja importando, haverá colisão entre os nomes do módulo e de seu arquivo.

Comment: Funcionou, era realmente o nome do arquivo, que por questão de teste coloquei o nome do arquivo de tkinter.py
Sou iniciante nessa ferramente, então não imaginei que poderia interferir
Agradeço a simplicidade e a clareza da informação. Vlw cara! :D

Comment: @Nathan-Santos se a resposta te ajudou marque-a como correta clicando no ✓

Answer (score 0):

Há um único erro em seu código, na **última linha**.

Você escreveu

```
root.mainloop
```

Quando o correto seria

```
root.mainloop()
```

Observe que o `mainloop` vem com parênteses, sendo portanto `mainloop()`

Seu código então fica:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

Label(root, text="teste").pack()

root.mainloop
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente assim:

```
# importa o módulo tkinter como tk
import tkinter as tk

# cria a janela principal
root = tk.Tk()

# cria um label
lbl = tk.Label(root, text="teste")

# mostra o label
lbl.pack()

# loop da tela
root.mainloop()
```